# Use React build in onScroll on window

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use ReactJS [onScroll](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#ui-events) on window object? There seem no example available on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to attach a scroll listener to the window object, you can do so in the `componentDidMount` hook, and remove it in the `componentDidUnmount` hook.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
  }

  onScroll = () => {
    console.log("Scrolling");
  };

  render() {
    return <div style={{ height: 3000 }}>Scroll me</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. Only problem I noticed is that for some reason on the initial website load the page jumps weird. Has this anything to do with his? It didn't happen before.

Comment: @supersize You're welcome! That's odd. Attaching an event listener should not effect the rendering of the page.

Comment: Probably something else then!

Answer (score 1):

The `onScroll` you are referring to is a prop for the scroll SyntheticEvent on a component.
Since the window object is not an react component, there isn't a way for you to declare something like that.

What you need to do is to attach scroll event listeners to the windows object on your component that is interested in the `scroll` event.